# I change list value in module but it does not change in params

Tags: form-fields-types

I have a list Joomla! form field in my XML, it works in the back end, I can change the dropdown.  When saved, the item stays the same.

When I `print_r($params)`

**The value is outputted as "true" and not the value** sometimes it appears as 1, no matter which option I choose.

If I change the PHP I obtain a

What could cause this given the option is selected correctly when I view it in the back end.

**XML**

```
        <field name="list"
               type="list"
               default=""
               label="MOD_KOY_YOUR_LOGO_LIST"
               description="">
            <option value="0">MOD_MY_MOD_OPTION_LOGO_ONLY</option>
            <option value="1">MOD_MY_MOD_OPTION_TEXT_ONLY</option>
            <option value="2">MOD_MY_MOD_OPTION_TEXT_AND_LOGO</option>
        </field>
```

Could it be possible that my use of multiple `showon=` are causing the issue?  all seem to work correctly, but some are nested.  By nested I mean if a = 1, then show b.  If b = 1 then show c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out that I needed to ensure my output was a number as opposed to true/false or 0/1 etc (boolean).

The way I did this was to set it as `intval`

```
$list= intval($params['list']);
```

Then I can call `$list` in my if statement and it will perform correctly.

Hope this helps someone else in the future if there's a better way please comment.

Comment: Please could you mark the answer as "accepted" so others know it has been solved? Thanks

Comment: Cheers for the reminder. It made me wait. Have done so now